# Export layers to files and keep the top layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export, photoshop-scripting, actions

I'm trying to add a logo to over 100 images. I have all of the images loaded into a PSD, and the logo as the very first (top) layer, locked into place. Is there an easy way to export layers to files and include the top, locked, logo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way I can add watermark to .jpg files (around 15000), en masse instead of one by one?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30083/is-there-any-way-i-can-add-watermark-to-jpg-files-around-15000-en-masse-inst)

Comment: It sounds like you got all images layered in one psd document. In that case you may have to first export the layers if you wanna follow answers in that link above. Photoshop has a script for exporting layers. I think I'd probably use [Photo Bulk](http://mac.eltima.com/bulk-image-editor.html), since I got it. --- This is maybe not where I'd use [this script](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38288/saving-each-layer-as-a-separate-image-photoshop-with-with-adjustments/38319#38319) but if you already got the images in one doc... Why not, I guess.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help.

Comment: If you can elaborate a bit. What doesn't work and why?

Comment: Well when I export to layers it doesn't keep the locked layers on top. I know there's a way to do it in Photoshop but I can't remember how for the life of me.

Comment: Photoshop doesn't have master pages, like Indesign does. There is not built in way to do what you want. The only way to do exactly what you want to do, is to use a script, such as the one I linked in my second comment. There is however a built in way to add a logo/watermark `(opaque or translucent, makes no difference)` to images in batch. This process is explained in cclark413's answer in that first link I commented. In your situation, you have to  first export the images as individual image files, so that you can then feed those files to Photoshop for batch processing.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it that way, not that I am saying that you couldn't do it (*see note below), just that I wouldn't.

The easiest way to apply logos to an image/watermarking would be to record an Action in Photoshop, and apply the action to a folder containing all the images, using File > Automate > Batch. The idea here is not to export PSDs with layers, but to export the images in a format such as JPEG/PNG for sharing on the web, etc. Here's how I would do it.

1. Open one of your images.
2. Open the Actions panel, click on the menu icon there, and choose the option that says "Allow Tool Recording"
3. In the actions panel in Photoshop, create a new action, and name it so you can find it easily, and hit the Record button.
4. Place, resize, and position the logo where you want it.
5. Using File > Export > Save for Web (Legacy), save the image in whatever format you want to a new folder.
6. In the Actions panel, hit the Stop button to stop recording the action.
7. Close everything that is open, and save nothing.
8. Click File > Automate > Batch
9. In the "Action" dropdown, choose the Action you just recorded.
10. Choose the source and destination folders.  The source folder is the folder containing all your images.  The destination is the folder where you want the images to be output.
11. In the options, uncheck "Override Action Open Commands" and uncheck "Override Action Save Commands".
12. click OK.

Warning: make sure you don't overwrite any of your original image files, because once you do that, you won't be able to undo it. It's safer to work on a copy of the folder containing the images.  When you need to supply the images without the logo/watermark, you should already have the originals saved without the watermark.

*Note: I suppose you could modify the Action recording to your requirements (Step 5: to save a PSD instead) if you really do need a PSD with layers, although personally I can't see the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can create layer comps for each layer and then export each layer comp to individual files. It does mean manually turning on the visibility for each picture layer and then creating a layer comp. this is the kind of repetitive task that would have me pulling my hair out.

A much simpler solution, if you have a copy of Lightroom, is to import all 100 images into Lightroom, then use the logo to create a watermark and then export all of the images with that watermark.

I had to do this exact task a few years ago, and it is what led me to begin using Lightroom in the first place.