# Photoshop Action Does Not Place Watermark File on Another File

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

CS4
I am trying to create a PS action that uses a separate source file for a watermark overlay in a large number of photos as below:

```
open photo file 1 
open watermark
file close watermark file
select all
shift drag to photo file 1 flatten photo file 1 save photo file 1    
close photo file 1
```

The action runs, but does not place the watermark. Created a test action simply move/overlay the watermark file onto an open photo file. Same result. Does not move the watermark. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not surprised - you say you open the watermark file, then close it.  What do you expect that will do? Are there other steps you missed out?

Comment: Keeping the watermark file open, then running the script below,  yields the same result. <cr> open watermark
file close watermark file
select all
shift drag to photo file 1 flatten photo file 1 save photo file 1    
close photo file 1

Comment: What I am trying to say is that's not going to work . . . the steps aren't in the right order, or there are steps missed out.

Comment: Oops. Timed out. Keeping the watermark file open, then running the script below,  yields the same result.

select all in watermark file -- 
shift drag to photo file 1 -- flatten photo file 1 -- save photo file 1 --
close photo file 1

Comment: This is not exactly a duplicate, as your question is about a specific issue in your own action, but if you want several different ways to apply a watermark, there's this question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/30083/2332

Answer (score 1):

I am not even sure what you mean by watermark but I'm gonna go and guess it's a png with a logo/copyright or another psd file.

Either way, remember that for the action to work at all times, you must have your png/psd in the same directory that you initially had it when creating the action (and with the same name), other than that, everything is easy.

Whenever I want to add such a file via action, I simply use Place (File > Place...). When using place, the action remembers the Path of the file you placed (as you can see when collapsing Place from action details) and every time you play the action, it will load the file from that Path (that's why I said at the beginning that your watermark has to remain in the same directory with the same name).

[image]